# How to run a set of js code on closing the system browser using inappbrowser?

Tags: cordova

I am using `window.open(url,"_system")` to open a link in system's browser.

Now I want to execute some set of code in my application once the browser is closed.

I tried using "exit" event listener but that didn't work when I clicked on back button to close the browser.

Can any one have solution?

Comment: Please post your code...

Comment: Events only work if you use _blank, not _system.